# Hierarchical Query to Self-Join Table Max 3 Times

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, self-join, hierarchical-query

I have an Oracle DB with a table with the following columns:

```
    ID | PARENTID | DETAIL1
    ------------------------
    1  | NULL     | BLAH1
    2  | 1        | BLAH2
    3  | 2        | BLAH3
    4  | 2        | BLAH4
    5  | NULL     | BLAH5
    6  | 5        | BLAH6
    7  | 6        | BLAH7
    8  | 5        | BLAH8
    9  | 5        | BLAH9
    10 | 8        | BLAH10
```

I prepared a self-join for

```
    SELECT    PARENT.ID AS "PID",
              PARENT.DETAIL1 AS "PDETAIL1",
              CHILD.ID AS "CID",
              CHILD.DETAIL1 AS "CDETAIL1" 

      FROM    table1 CHILD

      LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 PARENT

      ON      PARENT.ID = CHILD.PARENTID
      WHERE   PARENTID IS NOT NULL;
```

The output looks as shown below:

```
    PID | PDETAIL1 | CID | CDETAIL1|
    --------------------------------
    1   | BLAH1    | 2   | BLAH2   |
    2   | BLAH2    | 3   | BLAH3   |
    2   | BLAH2    | 4   | BLAH4   |
    5   | BLAH5    | 6   | BLAH6   |
    6   | BLAH6    | 7   | BLAH7   |
    5   | BLAH5    | 8   | BLAH8   |
    5   | BLAH5    | 9   | BLAH9   |
    8   | BLAH8    | 10  | BLAH10  |
```

Pretty straight forward. I would like to know if this self join can be done as a hierarchical/recursive query. The maximum nesting depth is 3. The target output should look like this:

```
    GPID | GPDETAIL1 | PID | PDETAIL1 | CID  | CDETAIL1 |
    ---------------------------------------------------
    1    | BLAH1     | 2   | BLAH2    | 3    | BLAH3    |
    1    | BLAH1     | 2   | BLAH2    | 4    | BLAH4    |
    5    | BLAH5     | 6   | BLAH6    | 7    | BLAH7    |
    5    | BLAH5     | 8   | BLAH8    | 10   | BLAH10   |
    5    | BLAH5     | 9   | BLAH9    | NULL | NULL     |
```

Google isn't helping me, there is a ton of information related to hierarchical queries, but nothing including self-joins AND hierarchical queries and most questions appear to be similar (on the surface), but nothing guiding me to what I need. I'm a SQL newbie so unless the answer is specific, I could be missing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there is a ton of information related to hierarchical queries, but nothing including self-joins AND hierarchical queries

You don't need both, the hierarchical query *is* the self-join.

You can get close starting with a hierarchical query like:

```
select connect_by_root (id) as gpid, connect_by_root(detail1) as gpdetail1,
  prior id as pid, prior detail1 as pdetail1,
  id as cid, detail1 as cdetail1,
  level as lvl, connect_by_isleaf as is_leaf
from table1
start with parentid is null
connect by prior id = parentid
```

[See the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns001.htm) for what connect_by_root and connect_by_isleaf mean. You're interested in the leaf nodes, but this:

```
select *
from (
  select connect_by_root (id) as gpid, connect_by_root(detail1) as gpdetail1,
    prior id as pid, prior detail1 as pdetail1,
    id as cid, detail1 as cdetail1,
    level as lvl, connect_by_isleaf as is_leaf
  from table1
  start with parentid is null
  connect by prior id = parentid
)
where is_leaf = 1;
```

... doesn't get quite what you want:

```
      GPID GPDETA        PID PDETAI        CID CDETAI        LVL    IS_LEAF
---------- ------ ---------- ------ ---------- ------ ---------- ----------
         1 BLAH1           2 BLAH2           3 BLAH3           3          1
         1 BLAH1           2 BLAH2           4 BLAH4           3          1
         5 BLAH5           6 BLAH6           7 BLAH7           3          1
         5 BLAH5           8 BLAH8          10 BLAH10          3          1
         5 BLAH5           5 BLAH5           9 BLAH9           2          1
```

From your sample output you don't want 5/BLAH5 in the parent columns of the last row as they are the grandparents; you want the child values promoted to parent status. You can manipulate the parent and child values a little though:

```
select gpid, gpdetail1,
  case lvl when 2 then cid else pid end as pid,
  case lvl when 2 then cdetail1 else pdetail1 end as pdetail1,
  case lvl when 2 then null else cid end as cid,
  case lvl when 2 then null else cdetail1 end as cdetail1
from (
  select connect_by_root (id) as gpid, connect_by_root(detail1) as gpdetail1,
    prior id as pid, prior detail1 as pdetail1,
    id as cid, detail1 as cdetail1,
    level as lvl, connect_by_isleaf as is_leaf
  from table1
  start with parentid is null
  connect by prior id = parentid
)
where is_leaf = 1;

      GPID GPDETA        PID PDETAI        CID CDETAI
---------- ------ ---------- ------ ---------- ------
         1 BLAH1           2 BLAH2           3 BLAH3 
         1 BLAH1           2 BLAH2           4 BLAH4 
         5 BLAH5           6 BLAH6           7 BLAH7 
         5 BLAH5           8 BLAH8          10 BLAH10
         5 BLAH5           9 BLAH9
```

But with only three fixed levels just joining again is simpler easier to understand...

Answer (score 2):

You just need to `join` to the table one more time to get the children.  So basically have a grandparent alias, parent alias and child alias and `join` accordingly:

```
select 
    gp.id as gpid,
    gp.detail as gpdetail1,
    p.id as pid,
    p.detail as pdetail1,
    c.id as cid,
    c.detail as cdetail1
from yourtable gp
    left join yourtable p on gp.id = p.parentid
    left join yourtable c on p.id = c.parentid
where gp.parentid is null
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/93df3e/1)